# Pandas Column Split a row with Conditional and create a separate Column

Tags: python, pandas, regex, group-by, split

It seems the problem is not difficult, but somehow I am not able to make it work. My problem is as follows. I have a dataframe say as follows:

```
       dfin 

           A      B     C
           a      1     198q24
           a      2     128q6
           a      6     1456
           b      7     67q22
           b      1     56
           c      3     451q2
           d      11    1q789
```

So now what I want to do is as follows, whenever the script will encounter a 'q', it will split the values and create a separate column with values starting from 'q'. The part before 'q' will remain in the original ( or maybe can crate a new column). So my desired output should be as follows:

```
        dfout 

           A      B     C        D
           a      1     198     q24
           a      2     128     q6
           a      6     1456
           b      7     67      q22
           b      1     56
           c      3     451     q2
           d      11    1       q789
```

So what I have tried till now is as follows:

```
       dfout = dfin.replace('\q\d*', '', regex=True)
```

Its creating one column without q, but I am not able to create the column D and not working as expected.

Any help/ideas will help and be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd


def get_input() -> pd.DataFrame:
    csv_text = """
         a      1     198q24
         a      2     128q6
         a      6     1456
         b      7     67q22
         b      1     56
         c      3     451q2
         d      11    1q789
         """.strip()
    return pd.DataFrame(map(str.split, csv_text.splitlines()), columns=["a", "b", "c"])


def split_on_q(df_in: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    df = df_in.c.str.split("q", expand=True)
    df_out = df_in.copy()
    df_out["c"] = df[0]
    df_out["d"] = _prepend_q(df[1])
    return df_out


def _prepend_q(series: pd.Series) -> pd.Series:
    return series.apply(lambda s: None if s is None else f"q{s}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(split_on_q(get_input()))
```

Output:

```
   a   b     c     d
0  a   1   198   q24
1  a   2   128    q6
2  a   6  1456  None
3  b   7    67   q22
4  b   1    56  None
5  c   3   451    q2
6  d  11     1  q789
```

Answer (score 1):

There will be multiple ways of doing this, but one way is to use `pd.concat` after splitting the column on 'q':

```
# temp dataframe
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df['C'].str.split('q').to_list(), columns=['C','D'])
# append to original 
df = pd.concat([df.drop(columns=['C']), df2], axis=1)
print(df)
```

PRINT:

```
   A   B     C     D
0  a   1   198    24
1  a   2   128     6
2  a   6  1456  None
3  b   7    67    22
4  b   1    56  None
5  c   3   451     2
6  d  11     1   789
```

Comment: col 'D' should have **q** before the digits according to the OP expected output. Also a blank string is expected rather than `None`.

Answer (score 1):

**Code**

use `str.extract`

```
df.assign(D=df['C'].str.extract(r'(q\d*)'))
```

output:

```
    A   B   C       D
0   a   1   198q24  q24
1   a   2   128q6   q6
2   a   6   1456    NaN
3   b   7   67q22   q22
4   b   1   56      NaN
5   c   3   451q2   q2
6   d   11  1q789   q789
```

---

I realized that I had overlooked the need to change the C column.suggestion from @user19077881. then use following code

```
df[['C', 'D']] = df['C'].str.extract(r'(\d+)(q\d+)*')
```

output:

```
    A   B   C       D
0   a   1   198     q24
1   a   2   128     q6
2   a   6   1456    NaN
3   b   7   67      q22
4   b   1   56      NaN
5   c   3   451     q2
6   d   11  1       q789
```

if you don want inplace to original df, use following code:

```
df[['A', 'B']].join(df['C'].str.extract(r'(?P<C>\d+)(?P<D>q\d+)*'))
```

---

**Example Code**

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = {'A': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 
         'B': [1, 2, 6, 7, 1, 3, 11], 
         'C': ['198q24', '128q6', '1456', '67q22', '56', '451q2', '1q789']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data1)
```

Comment: To produce the OP expected output, this would also need `str.extract(r'(\d+)q?')` to be applied to `df['C']`

Comment: @user19077881 Your suggestion is **completely different from questioner's desired output**. It would be better to run code before making a suggestion.

Comment: I am making the point that you retain the original col C whereas the OP wants only digits preceeding **q**

Comment: @user19077881 I misunderstood what you said. I apologize. I have corrected my answer.